# Custom background color for RelativeLayout in Android is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am facing a problem where using custom background color for RelativeLayout, is not working. The problem does not occur when I use a primary color (like RED). Any pointers will be appreciated.

I am pasting my view details here. It may not make sense as the map is not visible with this. But please ignore that bit. My concern is the background color.

**What works :**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="@string/map_key"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/friendListBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showAttendeesButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/show_attendees_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: What works]

**What doesn't work :**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="@string/map_key"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/friendListBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F0F3F6">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showAttendeesButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/show_attendees_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: What doesn't work]

Any pointers on this would be very appreciated!

Comment: But `#F0F3F6` is exactly the color in second picture. No?

Comment: `Custom background color for RelativeLayout in Android is not working` It **works perfectly**. The RelativeLayout background color changes accordingly.

Comment: I AM SO SORRY, everyone! :( This is absolutely embarrassing! :( I was using the wrong color code, and expecting another colour!
My sincere apologies for wasting your time! :(

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, the second bit of code works perfectly fine.

[The color works as it should](http://postimg.org/image/q8fin7f3v/)

Comment: I AM SO SORRY, @AlexR! :( This is absolutely embarrassing! :( I was using the wrong color code, and expecting another colour!
My sincere apologies for wasting your time! :(